What is heat in radiation?
In any system, to interact with the matter present in it, force will inevitably be involved no matter what kind of field or collision was it caused by (well collision also involve some field in almost all cases if I am not wrong).
Heat is defined as the part of the total energy transfer between the system and its surrounding that Work is not accounted for. (So can be interpreted from the first law of thermodynamics as well.)
But as stated above interaction with a system has to happen via forces; hence, if we talk about energy transfer via radiation, the changing electric and magnetic field causes force on the molecules of the body to which the EM wave is propagating to, and this causes increase in the random vibrations in that body and thus increases its temperature.
How can the energy transferred via the EM waves be said to be heat?

a solar sail get forces from em radiation but not heat ..... it's metallic/reflective vs being absorptive.

It's up to you whether you wish to treat electromagnetic radiation as work or heat.
If the receiving system is immobilized and absorbing radiation and the temperature change is of interest, you may get satisfying results by applying heat-transfer models such as Kirchhoff's law.
If relative motion is of interest, you may get satisfying results by applying a free-body diagram that incorporates momentum transfer from absorbed and reflected photons.
One could say that Nature is more concerned with energy and momentum conservation than divisions of energy transfer between work and heat.
